# Type struct std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> > has no component named end

Tags: c++, eclipse, stl, ifstream

This is really making me upset. I'm working with an ifstream in eclipse:

`infile = new std::ifstream(filePathParam, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);`

But when I want to access the `end` constant in a simple `seekg()` like such:

```
infile->seekg (0,infile->end)
```

It shows the following error:

```
Type struct std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> > has no component named end  
Type struct std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> > has no component named end  
Type struct std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> > has no component named end
```

But if I hover over the `infile->end` property during debugging, I can see the declaration!:

```
/// Request a seek relative to the current end of the sequence.
static const seekdir end =      _S_end;
```

So what is the problem?! I really need help with this because it's stopping the program from working at all if I can't load a simple file into it.

Thanks

EDIT: **@timrau**, this is the place where the ifstream object is created:

```
Lector::Lector(char* filePathParam, char* savePathParam)
{
    //infile = new std::ifstream(filePathParam,std::ifstream::binary);
    cout<<"File path param = "<<filePathParam<<endl;
    cout<<"Save Path param = "<<savePathParam<<endl;
    infile = new std::ifstream(filePathParam, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    outfile = new std::ofstream(savePathParam, std::ofstream::binary);

}
```

And here it's where I use the seekg() method:

```
void Lector::leerArchivo(long divisor,long posicion)
{
    free(textoLeido);
    infile->seekg (0,infile->end);//Sets the position of the next character to be extracted from the input stream.
    ...
}
```

Comment: [It compiles](http://ideone.com/SQwIJx). Please show more code.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @0x499602D2: I'm using GCC

Comment: @timrau: I know. These are runtime errors I'm getting, not compile time. I posted an edit of the OP

Comment: Do you mean that runtime error just happened on the seekg line?

Comment: It was a warning, actually, but yes.

Comment: Which version of gcc?

Comment: Give us a larger portion of your code that produces the error.